# RDRAND Funky Smelling output

Tags: boot, grub2

I was getting these weird errors after booting into Ubuntu:

[image: Link to a reddit post with same errors]

So I decided to add the "nordrand" parameter to my boot parameters and they stopped showing.

Question is this issue if not very well documented on the internet, and I have no idea what other issues could arise from adding this parameter.

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Comment: The systemd version (243.51-1-arch) suggests this is on an Arch Linux system?

Comment: Why is your image from a 3 year old post?  https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/f433xb/a_funky_smelling_output/

Comment: Regardless of where you got the image from, you might want to read:  https://www.phoronix.com/news/Linux-Drop-No-RdRand

Comment: Image is from a reddit post as I couldn't take a picture of my screen due to how fast it was. But the error is pretty much the same. I could take a picture and post it here